# Docker Build via GitLab Container Registry Failed

Tags: docker, gitlab, docker-image

I follow the instructions on [GitLab Container Registry](https://gitlab.com/help/user/packages/container_registry/index) but in the end I always receive the below error message on my Powershell line.

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  14.44MB
Error response from daemon: unexpected error reading Dockerfile: read /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder160316193/Dockerfile: is a directory
```

And, what I'm doing previously are:

1. I login with my credentials as my repo is a private one: `docker login registry.gitlab.com/<my_username>/<my_repo_name> -u <my_username> -p <my_personal_access_token>`
2. Then I typed `cd C:\Users\<username>\source\repos\<repo_name>`
3. I create a folder named Dockerfile on the same directory mentioned on second step
4. Finally, I run `docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/<my_username>/<my_repo_name> .` which should be very straightforward according to dear GitLab but I always go the error message I shared in the beginning of my question.

I run through on similar questions asked on internet and on this site, but can't figure it out what I am missing.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A Dockerfile is a **file** with instructions on how to build a docker image.
In your case it is just an empty folder.

Maybe you can start here: [Docker Get Started Build Image](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/)